# Different result set despite (seemingly) equivalent query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running the following queries (the only difference being that I'm applying a fix string in the first case and the predeclared variable *name* in the second one.

```
declare @name as varchar = 'directdebit'

select S.name as [Schema], T.name as [Table], 'Table' as Type
from sys.tables as T
inner join sys.schemas as S on S.schema_id = T.schema_id
where T.name like '%directdebit%'

select S.name as [Schema], T.name as [Table], 'Table' as Type
from sys.tables as T
inner join sys.schemas as S on S.schema_id = T.schema_id
where T.name like '%' + @name + '%'
```

Of course, I do realize that the concatenation of the string isn't equivalent and that the computer matches differently. However, I do get three different set sizes, depending on if I go without *where* (256 hits), if I go with concatenated *where* (163 hits) or if I go with the fixed *where* (45 hits).

What exactly am I being ignorant of? And how do I force the expression to be fully evaluated prior to filtration (adding parentheses didn't gave any difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your varchar is 1 char length:

```
DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR = 'directdebit';
SELECT '%' + @name + '%';
```

Result:

```
%d%
```

So it's quite straightforward that more results are found using `LIKE '%d%'` than `LIKE '%directdebit%'`

Declare your VARCHAR with fixed or `MAX` length:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX) = 'directdebit';
```

However, don't misuderstand. If you're casting some other value AS VARCHAR, it's going to work fine. For instance:

`SELECT CAST(1024 AS VARCHAR);` will return `1024` as as varchar, not a INT.

Answer (score 2):

*Always* use length when using `varchar()` in SQL Server:

```
declare @name varchar(255) = 'directdebit';
```

The default length in this context is 1, so `@name` is being set to `'d'`.

Comment: This must be one of the most gotcha'ish default lengths for a string. A *string* by its very definition should **by default** differ from *char*! At least in my head sitting on a body of a C# developer... +1 for clarity.